# ggplot2, how to add smoother to one variable only

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

Could anyone please help with adding a smoother to "BB" series only. I tried `stat_smooth()`, but it automatically adds smooth line to both series. Below is the code for demonstration purposes:

```
data1 = melt(data, id = 'Year')
ggplot(data1, aes(x = Year, y = value,colour=variable)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  ylab(label="Index") + 
  xlab("Year") + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue"),labels = c("BR", "BB"))+ theme(legend.position=c(0.8,0.9),legend.title=element_blank(),legend.background = element_rect(fill=NULL))+
  ggtitle("TITLE")
```

[image]

Comment: Your question does not contain a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4303162). It is therefore hard to understand your problem and give you an appropriate answer. Please make your data available (e.g. by using `dput()`) or use one of the example data sets in R. Also, add the minimal code required to reproduce your problem to your post.

Comment: You can subset your data in `stat_smooth`. Something like `stat_smooth(data = subset(data1, variable == "BB")`.

Comment: Thanks! Works flawlessly